# как MVC реализован у jsf

Tags: mvc, jsf

Пытаюсь понять как подход MVC реализован у jsf. Где модель, где контроллер, где вид? Для меня это как то размыто.

Если рассматривать простое приложение из одной xhtml страницы и одного бина для нее, то где конкретно что?

- xhtml страница очевидно это вид.
- Бин очевидно модель т.к. в нем содержится основная бизнес логика. (+ на его поля ссылается вид, а вид достает данные из модели).
- Однако, бин так же и контроллер, т.к. на его методы ссылается вид для совершения действий.

1. Правильно ли я определил что вид это xhtml страница?
2. Бин это модель или контроллер?
3. Надо ли создавать бин-модель, который содержит бизнес логику и на который ссылается вид, и второй бин-контоллер, на который будет ссылаться вид для обработки действий пользователя? Или как правильно решить проблему разноса бизнес логики и логики контроллера.
4. Какая логика вобще должна присутствовать в контроллере? Можно ли считать что контроллеры "запрятаны" в реализацию jsf, а методы на которые ссылается вид это нормальные методы модели и к контролеру не относятся?
5. Что вообще в jsf есть контроллер, что есть модель, что есть вид?

Comment: xhtml - страница, логично, что можно считать ее "видом". Бин это модель, потому что там логика апликации. А контроллер - это сервлет, он отвечает куда направить запрос с клиента. Вообще бизнес-логика не должна находиться в контроллере.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111387/understanding-jsf-as-a-mvc-framework

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/erainnovator.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/MVC-Design-Pattern.png?resize=1200%2C675&ssl=1